# How to get first name,last name,provider from a email address in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I try to get  first name, last name, provider from an email address "ben.ghol@gmail.com" but it doesn't work.

Table emailtable.
My code here:

```
     select 
        SUBSTR(email,1, INSTR(email,'.')-1) as firstname,
        SUBSTR(email,INSTR(email,'.')+1, INSTR(email,'@')-1) as lastname,
        SUBSTR(email,INSTR(email,'@')+1,INSTR(email,'.')-1) as "provider"
        from emailtable;
```

Comment: How do you know that the mail is always `firstname.lastname@provider`? You may have `john.smith1@provider.com`, `john.smith2@provider.com` for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third argument for `SUBSTR` is the length of the substring (and not the position of the end character).

You can use a nested sub-query to find the position of the separators and then use those values in `SUBSTR` in the outer query:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTR(email, 1, name_separator - 1) AS first_name,
       SUBSTR(email, name_separator + 1, at_separator - name_separator - 1)
         AS last_name,
       SUBSTR(email, at_separator + 1, domain_separator - at_separator - 1)
         AS domain
FROM   (
  SELECT email,
         INSTR(email, '.') AS name_separator,
         INSTR(email, '@') AS at_separator,
         INSTR(email, '.', INSTR(email, '@')) AS domain_separator
  FROM   emailtable
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE emailtable ( email ) AS
SELECT 'ben.ghol@gmail.com' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | DOMAIN |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | ben | ghol | gmail |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=011011702a42ebea0e960043246655d9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(email, '^[^.]+') as firstname,
       regexp_substr(email, '[^.@]+', 1, 2) as lastname,
       regexp_+substr(email, '[^@]+$') as provider
from (select 'ben.ghol@gmail.com' as email from dual) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=955b53d7e927cd5ea6d260739fcfd902) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

SUBSTR takes 3 parameters: input string, start position and length of substring.

You appear to be using end position as the 3rd parameter.

You can get the length to use as the 3rd parameter by doing (end position - start position + 1)